# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Seoul en route to China?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea

I am traveling to mainland China, and will be changing planes in Seoul. I have a 3 hour layover. Do I need a transit visa for that?

Comment: Is the trip booked at once? So Origin - China or have you booked it separately, Origin - Seoul and Seoul - China?
In the first case you don't have to pass through immigration and in the second case you do have to pass immigration. Depending on your country of residence you need a visa. If you have option two and aren't allowed to take a Visa on arrival you won't be allowed to board the aircraft at your home country

Comment: What is your citizenship?